# Login Blocked Using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to test a login automation for a website, and i have created a method which can properly identify the tags in the html, send the email and password values, and click the login button. The issue that i am facing is that i believe the website is blocking the login due to the text being inputted too fast. Logically i tried placing sleep statements, and breaking up the input text so its not being filled in all at one but have had no success. I have also tried using JavaScriptExecutor and Actions builder but also had no success with that either. Any input would help!

```java
wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//form[@method='post']"))); 
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("someemail@email.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("somepwd");
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
```

Comment: Where is the code with the sleeps? Do you know if the problem is with the keys being sent too fast, or is it with too many fields being entered too quickly?

Comment: I removed the Thread.sleep(timeunit) commands to make it cleaner. The problem is with the keys being sent too fast because i can enter email -> sleep -> enter pwd and still reach the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is entering keys too fast, you could do this to send one character at a time:

```
wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//form[@method='post']"))); 

usernameElement = driver.findElement(By.id("username"))
username = "someemail@email.com"
for c in username:
    usernameElement.sendKeys(c);
    sleep(.5)

password = "somepwd"
for c in password:
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(c);
    sleep(.5)
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
```

Comment: I have already tried looping over the username and pwd as strings and inputting character by character but that is to no avail.

Comment: ok, so what is the actual error, and where is it generated?

Comment: The problem that i am facing is that the site doesnt let me login in with the automated script, only on a manual entry

Comment: I know. But "How" is it blocking? Isn't that the problem we're solving? Perhaps we could explictly set the value of those fields and not use send_keys at all.

Comment: I believe that the login is being blocked due to the site being able to recognize that an automated testing system is being used. I have tried using ChomeOptions as well to "mask" the use of selenium but that also has not worked.

Comment: Have you tried changing your user agent yet?